# C# Json Dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, object, dynamic

I'm working with a  **Json dynamic object**.

Here's what i'm using to get data out of the object:

```
string = obj.item.today.price;
```

This works fine, the problem is that as soon as I have to start using numbers example :

```
string = obj.daily.10000;
```

It gives me an error

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: can you please put code

Comment: can you name a variable like: `var 1000 = 'ABC';` ???

Comment: It's not unusual for JSON libraries to support indexing syntax like `obj.daily["10000"]`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible to "`call` `10000 on daily object`" just because `10000` is NOT a valid [identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Let me explain what is going on here:

`JSON` parser generates some runtime type, inherited from some base `JSON` type (e.g `JsonObject`).
So, `obj` is some generated type, you call property `item` on it, it returns similar generated type, then you call `today` property and so on.

The last step is weird, there cannot be `10000` property on any type, generated or not.

But, *If library supports key-value access to objects*, you can try to write

```
obj.daily["10000"]
```

or cast obj to [JObject](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) (assume you are using JSON.NET)
and call [Property](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) method:

```
var jsonObject = (JObject) obj;
var propertyValue = jsonObject.Property("10000").Value;
```

Comment: Yeah I tried obj.daily["10000"], still giving me identifier error.
But how would it be possible then to Deserialize the json code if all the names are numbers?

Comment: @Tom library can maintain internal dictionary inside deserialized object and hold properties there.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Json.NET

```
string json = "{ dayly : { 1000 : 'asd' } }";
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine((d.dayly as JObject).Property("1000").Value);
```